# Angular form validation with skip some fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page which has a form in it named as profile updation and when a user comes to this page for any updation of his profile that time he only update 1 or 2 fields so every time form checks the form is valid or not then only saves in db, but I want to save if password and confirm password fields are not updated then also update his profile, but also when he wants to change password that time save button will get disabled and checks validation after that update the profile.

Means when user update only name that time also update the profile and also user update the password that time first check validation and then update the profile.

Save and `isValid` check:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.saveProfile = function(){
            if($scope.profile.$valid){
                ngProgress.start();
                user.saveProfile($scope.currentUser.details,function(response){
                    angular.copy(response,shared.data.currentUser);
                    notification.success($filter("il8n")("_ProfileUpdateMessage_"));
                    ngProgress.done();
                });
            }
        }

   $scope.isValidForm = function(){

            //if(($scope.profile.confirmpassword && $scope.profile.newpassword && $scope.profile.newpassword.$modelValue !== $scope.profile.confirmpassword.$modelValue))
            //    return true;
            if(!$scope.profile.$valid){
               if(($scope.profile.confirmpassword && $scope.profile.newpassword && $scope.profile.confirmpassword.$modelValue && $scope.profile.newpassword.$modelValue && ($scope.profile.newpassword.$modelValue.length == 0 || $scope.profile.confirmpassword.$modelValue.length == 0))){
                   return false;
               }
                if(($scope.profile.confirmpassword && $scope.profile.newpassword && $scope.profile.confirmpassword.$modelValue && $scope.profile.newpassword.$modelValue && $scope.profile.newpassword.$modelValue ===  $scope.profile.confirmpassword.$modelValue)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if($scope.profile.$valid && $scope.profile.$dirty)
                return false;

            if($scope.profile.newpassword.$invalid || $scope.profile.newpassword.$dirty &&  $scope.profile.confirmpassword.$invalid || $scope.profile.confirmpassword.$dirty){
                //$scope.profile.newpassword.$valid;
                //$scope.profile.confirmpassword.$valid;
                return false;
            }
            //if($scope.profile.newpassword.empty &&  $scope.profile.confirmpassword.empty ){
            //   return true;
            //}
            return true;
        }      
 });
```

Find plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mef49Fb3hW9gXlyaquDL?p=preview).

Comment: not sure I fully understand your issue, but will `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` help?

Comment: my issue is when a user update his profile that time without entering password field, if he only changes name field then also update a user profile and also when user wants to change password that time checks validation and update profile.

Comment: I am just about to code up my profile page. I will be setting the password to "" and only validating if not empty , validation will pass if they match. I am using a directive that set the form to invalid if they don't match.

Comment: I try to avoid coded validation. I let the directive set the field and form to invalid. I found the directive on git

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you want form where user can update few fields then update them?

About password change, I think you should split profile information from password change into two separate forms, where user can change password without changing other data. Then if user wants to change other user data (which is binded to ng-model and placed already into text boxes), then user change data and saves them.

Problem solved. If u want so, i can try to edit your plunk and show how it would look like :)

Plunk - [New format](http://plnkr.co/edit/YXOPVt?p=preview)

```
<form ng-submit="SAVE FUNCTION HERE">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="proxima-nova nova-bold form-label">Change Password</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label data-ng-class="{'state-error': profile.newpassword.$invalid && profile.newpassword.$dirty && profile.newpassword.$error.strongPassword}">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new password" data-ng-model="currentUser.details.password" name="newpassword" data-password-check="currentUser.details.password" />
            </label>
            <div class="ng-cloak invalid" data-ng-show=" profile.newpassword.$error.strongPassword && profile.newpassword.$dirty && profile.newpassword.$invalid">
              Password should contain atleast one special character, number, uppercase letter, and atleast 8 characters.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label data-ng-class="{'state-error': profile.confirmpassword.$dirty && currentUser.details.password != currentUser.details.password_confirmation}">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" data-ng-model="currentUser.details.password_confirmation" name="confirmpassword" />
            </label>
            <div class="ng-cloak invalid" data-ng-show="profile.confirmpassword.$dirty && currentUser.details.password != currentUser.details.password_confirmation">
              Passwords do not match
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Also in form fieldset you can add save button with type="submit", then that button will call that function which is defined into form tag

```
<form ng-submit="SAVE FUNCTION HERE">
```

Comment: @user3608377 In weekend I will make that plunk if that is ok with u

Comment: @user3608377 here u go - i didnt mess with funcionality but i just rearranged input fields and put into seperate forms plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/YXOPVt?p=preview . Look more into angular docs about angular forms. You can bind to input fields only properties you have to change, then call submit.

Comment: hi @Imants as u suggested i have used two forms for profile and for change password.
but the issue i have now by submitting one form the save button of another form is getting enabled and i have no idea why. the ng-disabled attribute of the other save button doesnt changes but still it enables!! any help is appreciated . thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait. You have now 2 forms and for each you got a save button?

Comment: Put plnkr in coments to see where is the problem